# Need help changing appendChild to replaceChild

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

Is there an easy way to change this from `appendChild` to `replaceChild`?

This of course continuously adds more ele.  Also for some reason it doesn't put the value inside the `DIV` or `SPAN`, seems to put below it.

```
var para = document.createElement("P");
var total = document.createTextNode(parseFloat((subT + tax).toFixed(2))) ;

para.appendChild(total);

document.getElementById("total_id").appendChild(para);
```

Its updating this:

```
<div class="prod_totals">Order Total: $<span id="total_id"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use `innerHTML` instead of `appendChild`

```
document.getElementById("total_id").innerHTML = parseFloat((subT + tax).toFixed(2));
```

Because you're not inserting any user input values inside the `total_id` element and also as far as the question mentions, its data is not later passed to the server I think you'll be safe using the `innerHTML` here. But if for any reasons you'd still like to use `replaceChild` you could do it like this:

```
var para = document.createElement("P");
var total = document.createTextNode(parseFloat((subT + tax).toFixed(2))) ;

para.appendChild(total);

var existingText=document.getElementById("total_id").querySelector('p');
if(existingText){
    document.getElementById("total_id").replaceChild(existingText, para);
}
else{
    document.getElementById("total_id").appendChild(para);
}
```

Comment: I did originally have that, but innerHTML is weak on security and vulnerable to XSS attacks

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer has solved the issue, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: I don't think `innerHTML` is the way to go here, it's intended to change HTML content why whould we use it for editing text content, also it's bad idea to put a `p` inside a `span`.

Comment: @chsdk we could also use `innerText` if we only want to change the text, and yes it is always a bad idea to place a block level element into an inline level element!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use [`.replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) here, you can simply check if the `element` was already created before trying to update it.

Note that you were trying to insert a `p` element inside a `span` which is wrong and **is not valid HTML markup**, you can see in [the **span** documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span#wikiArticle) that its possible content is only [**Phrasing content**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content), so you better use another `span`.

This is how should be your code:

```
var para = document.querySelector("#total_id span");
if (!para || para.length == 0) {
  para = document.createElement("span");
}
var total = parseFloat((subT + tax).toFixed(2));
para.innerText = total;
document.getElementById("total_id").appendChild(para);
```

And here's a **Demo:**

```js
var para = document.querySelector("#total_id span");
if (!para || para.length == 0) {
  para = document.createElement("span");
}
var total = new Date();

para.innerText = total;

document.getElementById("total_id").appendChild(para);
```

```html
<div class="prod_totals">Order Total: $<span id="total_id"></span></div>
```